# Checking charcters in a string and outputing a Single message

Tags: list, python-3.x, iteration

```
a_lst = ['chair','gum','food','pizza']
letter = 'x'
for word in a_lst:
  if letter not in word:
    print ('no',letter)

  elif letter in word:
    print ('yes',letter)
```

Output:

```
no x
no x
no x
no x
```

Is there a way i can iterate though each item in "a_lst", check if each item has letter 'x'.  if no item has letter 'x' print 'no x' just Once. If a word contains letter 'x', print 'yes x' just Once.

I think my logic is flawed somewhere.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
letter = 'x'
result = [a for a in a_lst if letter in a]
if result:
    print('yes', letter)
else:
    print('no', letter)
```

**Explanation**:
`result` will be `[]` if none of the words in `a_lst` has the letter. When you do a `if result` on an empty list, it returns `False`, otherwise it returns `True`. The conditional statements check and print the output statement accordingly.

Another way to do it in python is to use the `filter` function:

```
if filter(lambda x: letter in x, a_lst):
    print('yes', letter)
else:
    print('no', letter)
```

Yet another way to do it is to use `any`:

```
if any(letter in word for word in a_list):
    print('yes', letter)
else:
    print('no', letter)
```

`any(letter in word for word in a_list)` returns True if any of the words have the letter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
a = ['chair', 'gum', 'food', 'pizza']

letter = 'a'

result = 'no ' + letter
k = 0

for i in a:

    if letter in a[k]:
        print(a[k])
        result = 'yes ' + letter

    k += 1

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `any` function!

```
if any(letter in word for word in a_lst):
    print('yes', letter)
else:
    print('no', letter)
```